# Strapi mongo _id without ObjectId

Tags: node.js, strapi

Now Strapi save mongo data `_id` is `ObjectId("606ff2743de6034490e02589")` , how to config strapi to only save `"606ff2743de6034490e02589"`

Answer (score -1):

as described I believe you are using mongo db. You can achieve by using `mongoose` package for define your collection schema.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{ name: 'string', size: 'string' },
{ id: true}
);
const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```